# QField QFieldSync issues

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I have a fairly simple geopackage to edit with QField from QGIS. I've packaged the project, and put it on my mobile phone (Android 9) made some edits for a bunch of data I'm trying to verify. Then I've closed QField copied the folder back from my mobile and then synced.

I can see the changes I've made in QField, but the changes are not syncing to the data in QGIS. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "Copy the project folder from your device to your computer and use the Synchronize from Qfield menu to synchronize your changes" (When you set it up there was settings for 'Offline' use in Layer configuration.) https://qfield.org/docs/synchronise/qfieldsync.html (as your offline layer will have a layer+crc like 'polylines_982eb34a_5474_4a74_bae2_25f09d508cec' which will be merged back into the project.

Comment: I created the project, used the offline settings for my layers, copied project folder to my device, made changes, copied project folder back to my computer. There's a .qgs, data.gpkg, data.gpkg-shm, and data.gpkg-wal in that folder. I pointed the project back to the folder and synchronized off that folder. I didn't see the changes made committed to the project.

Comment: Have you saved your project as a .qgs-Project? QField doesn't work with .qgz

Answer (score 0):

Presence of data.gpkg-shm and data.gpkg-wal files could signify, that you copied data.gpkg file, when it was opened. So one of possible solutions could be, that you will close QGIS and your project (if they have not be closed yet) on Android device and for sure restart your device - this restart ensures that all cached informations are written to a file system. Then try copy your files again. In some cases this helps.
Syncing back can also sometimes fail, when original project file was modified after syncing to a device and before syncing back to QGIS.