# QField Sync issues

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I use QField 1.9.6 on Android 10, QGIS 3.20 and QField Sync 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a fairly simple geopackage to edit with QField from QGIS. It is set as offline editing. Producing the package goes fine and there is no problem to edit it in QField.
I noticed that `data.gpkg-shm` and `data.gpkg-wal` are present as soon as I open the .qgs project in QField and they do not disappear afterwards, unless you open another .qgis project in QField. Restarting the device as suggested does not wipe them. A finalizing edit button in QField to close every project would make sense.

But anyway the sync does not work, either with or without the presence of the `data.gpkg-shm` and `data.gpkg-wal` files. If I open the `data.gpkg` in QGIS, the changes are there, but the sync just fails. I did not change anything in the project in QGIS between the packaging for QField and the Sync.

Any clue?

I have exactly the same issue than [QField QFieldSync issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413032/qfield-qfieldsync-issues/415086) and I tested the proposed solution, but it does not work for me.

The logs only show the following:

> 2021-10-28T19:09:38 INFO
> QFieldSync : Opened original project /mytreefolder/Qfield_whatever.qgz

Hard to say if this is supposed to be normal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved as soon I updated Qfield for v1.10